# ffmpeg inside chrome extansion

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ffmpeg

hello I am trying to use the ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm library inside chrome extension
the library is loaded inside react component that is located inside an iframe

the problem is when I try to load I got an error that I cannot download the core files [image]

I tried to use the example library for chrome extension but also got an error **"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined error. "**

the files are web_accessible_resources inside the manifest

I am using manifest version 3

Comment: Is this a content script or action page? Is the iframe served from extension or a web server?

Comment: this is an action page and it served from the extansion

Comment: Are you sure the file is reachable from the extension? Normally `node_modules` shouldn't be included in the frontend code. Also, which "example library for chrome extension" did you try? By "files are web_accessible_resources" do you mean files are located outside or the extension?

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing more informations about your extension. Would you mind uploading it or minimal example reproducing your problem?
You can also open a bug to https://crbug.com if you believe this is a bug in Chrome.